# What is OEX (Open Exchange Protocol?) and can I call such APK from my app?

Tags: android, chess

I am not sure if I understood it correctly or not, but it seems that there is [Stockfish Engines OEX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc.chess.engine.stockfish), and even though it is a separately installable APK, it is a library intended to be used by other apps. The description says:

> To use these engines, you need a chess application that is compatible with the Open Exchange protocol.

But it does not give any further details. I searched Google for OEX, but I got nothing. I searched for "Open Exchange protocol", but the only search result was something about a mail server. This seems to be [the source code of the library app](https://github.com/c4akarl/StockfishChess) but it has no description either.

So, I wonder

1. Is this "Stockfish Engines OEX" something that a third-party applications call and get the result (like a chess move) from?
2. If so, how can I use it? For example, how can I start a new game, input a user move and get the AI's chess move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the archived repository [Chess Engine Support](https://code.google.com/archive/p/chessenginesupport-androidlib/) with with I could successfully discover and use OEX chess engines from my demo application.

From their homepage :

> This Android library offers a standardized way for app developers to

> provide chess engines to other chess apps

> use provided chess engines in other chess apps

The source code is [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/chessenginesupport-androidlib/source/default/source?page=5)

(Edit :
There are no sources any more there, but you can have a look [there](https://github.com/gkalab/chessenginesupport-androidlib))

Notice that the DroidFish application uses [this library code](https://github.com/peterosterlund2/droidfish/blob/master/DroidFishApp/src/main/java/com/kalab/chess/enginesupport/ChessEngineResolver.java)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest updates for "Chess Engines OEX" and "Stockfish Engines OEX"?

...
Recommended chess GUIs:

- Chess for All
- DroidFish
- Scid on the go
- Chess PGN Master
- Chess for Android
- Chess (Jeroen Carolus)
- Acid Ape Chess

In these apps you will find an option "Select engine". Follow the further instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I chose another approach:

1. I compiled the latest stockfish for android ARM64 v8:
   https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/files/9652034/stockfish-armv8-270922.zip
2. I put the executable in /data/local/tmp/
3. I ran it with: nc -L -p 50000 stockfish &
4. from "Chess for android" I just added a network engine pointing at 127.0.0.1 port 50000   and it works perfectly.